# Getting an exotic armor with different prefixes

Tags: guild-wars-2

[Twilight Arbor armor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Twilight_Arbor_armor) can be picked with one of the following three prefixes: Rampager's, Rabid or Magi's. But I'd like the Berserker's prefix on the armor pieces. Is it possible to have this specific armor with the Berserker's prefixes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. I've had the same problem. However, most of these armor options are meant to be used for transmuting the skins anyway (i.e. buy the item to be used as a skin, buy a transmutation crystal off the item store and merge the item with a crafted/bought/dropped one with correct stats).

However:
According to [recent datamining](http://an.reddit.com/r/Guildwars2/comments/1jswc4/data_mining_upcoming_features_and_changes_from/) of the client files it seems like ArenaNet might introduce special itemshop items allowing you to reconfigure/change prefixes on items. Although it's yet to be seen how much they'll cost, whether they'll indeed appear and whether they'll allow you to reconfigure such "set" items as well, considering there probably aren't other versions (like Berserker) right now.

Comment: Where do you see your latter comment? And wouldn't transmutating work somehow?

Comment: Of course transmuting is an option. As for datamining: Just read the first few lines in the table, starting with *"Customize your Stats!"*.

Comment: Allright, then I'll be transmuting them. I despite the fact that the name probably depends on the one with the original stats (nót the TA armor set then) thus losing the 'cool name'. Although it's the skin I want so I shouldn't be too upset about it. I'm curious as to what the new additions to the game will be, but by the time I've managed to farm up enough tokens, I'll be able to see it ingame. Thank you @Mario.

Comment: They will need to provide a way to allow players to change items stats when they drop magic find. Ref: https://www.guildwars2.com/en/news/looking-ahead-guild-wars-2-in-2013//

Comment: @DavidYell I forgot about that. I've got quite a few runes/items to boost my Magic Find but you made me remember they'd drop it. This makes my decision easier!